# Is it more/less efficient for MapReduce to read text or binary files on a network file system?

Tags: file-io, binary, mapreduce, mpi

Is it more/less efficient for MapReduce to read text or binary files on a network file system?

What about if I'm using MPI? Does it send files to each computing node to be saved to disk? Or does it just remain in main memory, in which case the file format wouldn't matter?

Comment: Also I'm wondering if the file is binary, and we are doing say, a word search, will MapReduce have to do extra work to convert binary to string, to do the comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

To guess the answer of my own questions:

I think MapReduce would rather use text files, because they only reading not writing, and have to compare text to text anyway, so avoid converting from binary to text.

I don't MPI gives a shit. It reads once and sends other nodes the data through memory buffer, not files.

My final is today that's the story I'm sticking with.